# How to set up automatice trigger for azure file share

Tags: azure-files

How to set up trigger for Azure file share? When file is placed in azure file path it should automatically trigger the ADF pipeline to send the file to destination.

Answer (score 0):

I found a accepted answer about this question.

> Unfortunately we do not have an existing feature in ADF that could trigger your pipeline based on new events in Azure File Share. We have event triggers in ADF but that doesn't support Azure File Share.

[image]

[How to set up automatice trigger for azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114300/how-to-set-up-automatice-trigger-for-azure-file-sh.html)